# Is soapUI the best web services testing tool/client/framework?

Tags: web-services, testing

I have been working on a web services related project for about the last year.  Our team found [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org) near the start of our project and we have been *mostly*(*) satisfied with it (the free version, that is).

My question is: are there other tools/clients/frameworks that you have used/currently use for web services testing and would recommend?

(*) There are some weird GUI glitches that appear once in a while.  As is mentioned by some of the answers, we attributed this to a memory leak.

Comment: -1: totally subjective, and a compound question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use soapUI, and it's generally pretty good.  Be aware that it seems to leak memory, and eventually it will no longer save your project, so save regularly!

This is about the only hassle I have with it (other than the general ugliness that almost every Java application has!), and I can't live without it.

Answer (score 4):

There's an eclipse plugin that allows you to do web service discovery, testing, etc - see [Eclipse Web Services Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/ws/).

I think it's much better than SoapUI, at least on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Call it laziness but I kind of gave up looking a while after I found SoapUI - its not perfect (what is) but it does its job very well (especially given the price).

More importantly given that there is scripting to allow you to set up automated tests we're heading towards an investment in the product.

Might be nice if it was better on Windows (we do .NET development, mostly ASP.NET) but for the price... (-:

Answer (score 2):

I've released an open source project for generating web service requests and making calls.

Whether something is the best is pretty subjective but give the program a try and compare it for yourself

Download it at http://drexyia.github.io/WsdlUI/

Answer (score 1):

We've been using SoapUI since 1.x (will soon be adopting 3.0 from 2.5.1) and are all happy.
It's much more stable when running with native LnF (File - Preferences - UI Settings - Native LF).
I know it's available as an Eclipse plugin as well, but last I tried I failed to find how to add JAR-files to it (i.e. bin/ext in the stand-alone variant).